# What is the best way to know when and which design pattern to implement in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets assume i am building an e-commerce website with Angular, Node.js, Express and Mysql. How do I know which is best suited

1. Singleton pattern
2. Factory pattern
3. Observer
4. MVC

Or any other pattern or combination of different patterns

Comment: MVC is a better choice among them.

Comment: There is no correct answer to a question like this.  The answer is always "it depends" upon the circumstances, upon the type of architecture you want, upon the type of interface works best for your situation, upon the extensibility you want, upon the needs of the interface, etc...   I could imagine a project where I might use all four of your options in different situations within the same project.  These are all just tools that can be used to achieve a local objective and there are lots of different and "good" ways to use those tools.

Comment: ***How do I know which is best suited?***.  Once you learn each pattern, it will become clear to you which problems in your application will benefit from which pattern.  We can't tell you that.  You have to learn them and then apply those tools to each piece of your project.  This is called "software design".  Your learn the tools, learn examples of when they work well and then pick the right tool to apply to each piece of your project.  There is no universal answer.

Comment: Feel free to read what is commonly referred to as the [Gang of Four Design Patterns](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/gofpatterns.aspx). A google search will find the original book these came from and many more web site references that discuss them.  Read, learn, pick the right tool for a given piece of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, most of the architects go for MVC pattern when it comes to enterprise level applications where you have large amount of components. Comparing the Singleton and Factory patters, these patterns have their own advantages.

**1. Singleton:** 
The Singleton pattern is easy to remember. As the name implies, it will provide you with a single instance of an object, and guarantee that there are no duplicates.
At the first call to use the instance, it is created and then reused between all the parts in the application that need to use that particular behavior.
You'll use the Singleton pattern in many different situations. 
**For example:**

1. When you want to use the same connection to a database to make every
   query
2. When you open a Secure Shell (SSH) connection to a server to do a few tasks, and don't want to reopen the connection for each task.

**2. Factory:** 
The Factory method pattern (or simply, Factory) is probably the second-best known and used design pattern in the industry. Its purpose is to abstract the user from the knowledge of the struct he needs to achieve for a specific purpose, such as retrieving some value, maybe from a web service or a database. The user only needs an interface that provides him this value. By delegating this decision to a Factory, this Factory can provide an interface that fits the user needs. It also eases the process of downgrading or upgrading of the implementation of the underlying type if needed.

Example of Factory pattern can be a **Payment System in Website**, where you have single entity called **Payment**, but you provide multiple options of payment like **Credit Card, Debit Card, Net banking** etc etc. Your **Payment** entity is a Factory of multiple functions that have different nature.

Now coming back the best pattern in case of E-Commerce, when it comes to primary structure, I would suggest MVC. But you have to make use of all these patterns for  building a solid solution for different parts in the application.

Answer (score 2):

Design pattern solves a commonly occurring problem. It means for specific problem, you can solve by applying a specific design pattern. For a complete application, you can not use only one design pattern. There can be multiple patterns for specific use cases. In a web application also, you can use Singleton if you want only one instance every time. According to Gang of Four, there are 23 design patterns. I suggest you go through each patterns. MVC is a pattern where you want to separate out the views and the controllers. Besides, there is no rule of thumb to apply a specific pattern.